# Is there a statistical test for matrix symmetry?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, model-comparison, symmetry

I have collected some data and done some processing until the question I'm faced with is - "is the data matrix $X$ a symmetric matrix?".  Note that elements of $X$ represents event counts.

Eyeballing the matrix $X - X^{\text{T}}$ suggests this may be true, but unsurprisingly the largest residuals just correlate with the areas where I have relatively little data.

Is there some statistical test that asks whether a matrix is Symmetric?

At the moment I'm tempted to simply view the matrix as a joint PDF and then perform a test to see if the distribution represented by $X$ is different from the distribution represented by $X^{\text{T}}$, but it seems like there should be a more precise test for this context?

Comment: Are the off-diagonal counts independent?

Comment: No, we can't assume they are.

Comment: I'm toying with a permutation test, but not sure how to go about constructing one

Comment: It would help to have a model of this data matrix.  Are you trying to suggest it is a random matrix in which the entries are counts and the counts are a matrix of random variables whose matrix of corresponding expectations is symmetric?